# display post link in wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress

i have a following bit of code that pulls out the featured image on pages, however how do i have a link back to the original post that it came from?

this is my code:

```
    <?php

            $mypages = get_pages( array() );

            $mypages_featured_images = array();

                foreach ( $mypages as $mypage ) {
                    if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) ) {
                        $mypages_featured_images[] = get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID );
                    }
                }
        ?>

        <?php
            if ( false !== $mypages_featured_images ) {
        ?>
                <ul>
                <?php
                    foreach ( $mypages_featured_images as $featured_image ) {
                        echo '<li>' . $featured_image . '</li>';

                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

ideally i would like to put the title with a link back to the post where the image is from.

thanks in advance

Comment: [get_permalink( $mypage->ID )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just simplify everything? There's no need for the second loop at all...

```
<?php

    $mypages = get_pages( array() );

    if ( $mypages ) {
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach ( $mypages as $mypage ) {
            if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $mypage->ID ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) . '</a></li>';
            }
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, there was nothing wrong at all with your original code...until you try to add something like a permalink to the markup. Glad it helped!